# can't setExecutable for files in app specific storage in Android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage, android-storage

I have a cross-compiled binary for Android, and want to run it with `runtime.exec`

But after downloading it top the [app specific storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific)(in my case `storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.sampleApp/files/binary/sample`) I can not set the permission with `setExecutabe` for it, which make it impossible for running.

Also `adb shell chomd +x storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.sampleApp/files/binary/sample` does not work either.

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I already have the permission declared:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After downloading, `file.setExecutable(true)` just return false; and permission is still `-rw-rw----`. My Download Part code probably related here:

```kotlin
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            request.setMimeType("application/octet-stream")
            request.setTitle("Downloading binary") 
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(
                this,
                null,
                "binary/sample"
            )
            (getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager).euqueue(request)
```

Comment: At minimum, that appears to be blocked [for Android 10+ for apps with `targetSdkVersion` of 29 or higher](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission).

Comment: @CommonsWare that is a pity, thanks for the quick answer